# Will I be able to re-select travel document with Ryanair during check-in?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork

I have a Ryanair account and during all my previous travels I used passport as my travel document. Now I have a new flight reservation and I will need to travel with my identity card instead. There is still few weeks until check-in is available. So far, I noticed that under Manage Booking it does not allow me to change the document:

[image]

However, I don't remember if during booking I chose passport anywhere. I also don't know if it is by any chance a default document by now. Will I be able to select identity card during online check-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while I noticed that it is possible, so I post the answer that might be useful for someone. First, I completed **myProfile** details which I haven't done so far, I added phone number, nationality, date of birth. After that, it showed me my currently added travel document that I have got saved on myRyanair account which was my passport. But there also appears an option **Add another document**. So you need to click this and add the details of your ID card and save. From now on, when you click on Check-in button for your flight reservation a new document should appear in the scroll down menu and you can select it. Thankfully, I didn't have to pay anywhere :-)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. Feel free to accept this answer when the (green) tick next to it shows up for you.